# Complex Cloud Dataflow pipelines don't show the execution graph in the developer console

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We are implementing a fairly complex pipeline composed of several GroupBy and Combine chained together. In addition to that, the pipeline it's also applying a KeyedPCollectionTuple.

This pipeline executes successfully however the graph doesn't show in the Google developer's console. Only the logs are shown. 
The steps are also missing.

Is there any way of get them to show?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble! Can you provide a job id so we can investigate from our side? Also, it would be good to know whether (a) a refresh helps, and (b) if UI fails to load just in the first few minutes after the job is run, or continues to have problems even well after the job is complete.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Frances thanks for answering so quick. I tried a couple of refreshes and the graph is still not showing. JobID 2015-09-09_21_23_09-16054981068465705666

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by a failure to display graphs if any of the transforms have an assigned name which is empty.

Github issue [#58](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/58) has been created to address this issue.

In the meantime, look at your code and make sure any invocation of `.apply(name, transform)` never has an empty `name` string, or a name starting with a `/` character. Also make sure that any uses of `setName` and `named` satisfy these requirements.